# Recover property key/value

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am playing with ECMAScript 6 symbols and maps in Node.JS v0.11.4 with the `--harmony` flag. Consider the following.

```
var a = Map();
a.set(Symbol(), 'Noise');

// Prints "1"
console.log(a.size);
```

Can the value `'Noise'` be retrieved given the property is identified by an "anonymous" symbol key, which is guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: i don't know about a leak, but you can't get back to the value without a ref to the Symbol()  return...

Comment: I have no idea how ES 6 symbols work, but can't you enumerate the a object? `for (var key in a) alert(a[key]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to do it in node.js because the current version of v8 hasn't implemented iteration as indicated in this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1793).

We can confirm that by looking at the source code of v8's [collection.js](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/9abb3fe0d216c563f75e4d4ac0cde3e24582d01d/src/collection.js#L217):

```
InstallFunctions($Map.prototype, DONT_ENUM, $Array(
    "get", MapGet,
    "set", MapSet,
    "has", MapHas,
    "delete", MapDelete,
    "clear", MapClear
));
```

But, as can be seen in [ECMAScript 6 wiki](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3asimple_maps_and_sets), there should also be `items()`, `keys()`, and `values()`. v8 probably didn't implement these methods before, because it didn't support generators. But now [it does](http://wingolog.org/archives/2013/05/08/generators-in-v8) since May of this year. It should be a just a matter of time until this is implemented.

If you need to have this functionality now, you can use [map-set-for-each](https://github.com/arv/map-set-for-each) which polyfills `forEach`. You will need to modify it to add `case 'symbol':` after `case 'object':`.

```
a.forEach(function(value, key) {
  if (value === 'Noise') {
    console.log('Give mak the bounty');
  }
});
```

When v8 implements iteration of `Map` you will be able to find `Noise` like this:

```
for (let [key, value] of a) {
  if (value === 'Noise') {
    console.log('Upvotes for future');
  }
}
```